# Bootstrap Select not working in MDBootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm using [MDBootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/) in one of my project.

I'm not premium user of `MDB`. So I can't use `MDB Select`.

But [Bootstrap Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) is not working perfectly inside `MDB`.

Here's a sample picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MDB Select is only available for premium users. You can't use it. However you can use any other plugin. If you want to have material design, you can use [Materialize css](http://materializecss.com/).